# Unable to browse a service with dns-sd

Tags: linux, bonjour, avahi, mdns

I have cross compiled and install mdns responder on to my target machine which runs on Linux. I have tried to register a service with the following command:

```
dns-sd -R "My Test" _printer._tcp. . 515
```

But when I try to browse for that service using `dns-sd -B _printer` I am not getting any service name. Kindly help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @grawity Thanks for the help. It is working fine now. I am using mDNS as it is required for my project and Avahi should not be used. I have solved the error by stopping AVAHI and restarting the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have solved the error by stopping AVAHI and restarting the system.